# Onchange with more than one select fields

Tags: javascript, php

I have a dashboard with data filled from the database.

First, I have a Select working as a filter like

> "*select X from Y where fieldX = (The key from select goes here)*"

and then the data from dashboard changes.

Currently, I'm using the onchange property. Right after the select is fired the dashboard changes without a submit button.

But now, I want to put more Selects (like 4, like a form). The problem is that right after a select is fired the dashboard changes. Not a problem with just 1 select (expected effect), but I want to select more Selects fields to add more filters on my dashboard like

> "*select X from Y where fieldX = (The key from selectX goes here) and fieldZ = (The key from selectZ goes here) and [...]*"

(note that the user chooses the filters. Some selects fields may be selected or not)

My question if there is a way, using onchange (or not), to do that. Maybe using a submit button or something?

Currently I'm using something like this:

```
//PEGANDO O SELECT REGIONAL PARA O GRÁFICO 
$('select#SELECTID').on('change', function (e) {
  var SELECTID = this.value;
  //url 
  control('ocupantes-aptos/dashboard?SELECTID =' + SELECTID , 'content');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same thing. You bind the event to all involved SELECTs. And if you have an ID (# selector) you need not specify SELECT. In the callback, you now have to explicitly retrieve each control's value:

```
$('#selectId1, #selectId2, #selectId3').on('change', function () {
  var s1 = $('#selectId1').val();
  var s2 = $('#selectId2').val();
  var s3 = $('#selectId3').val();
  //url 
  control('ocupantes-aptos/dashboard?SELECTID =' + s1 , 'content');
});
```

Or you can give a specific class to all those controls:

```
$('select.grupo1').on('change', ...
```

with

```
<select id="selectId1" class="grupo1">
    ...
```

Note: jQuery also has functions to efficiently serialize a form or a set of controls, so that you need not specify all those `val()`s.

## Example

In this example we send *all* the 'grupo1' values whenever any of them changes. The HTML looks like a series of elements:

```
<select name="s[1]" class="grupo1">...</select>
<select name="s[2]" class="grupo1">...</select>
```

Or even shorter, using "#grupo2 select" instead of "select.grupo1":

```
<div id="grupo2">
<select name="s[1]">...</select>
<select name="s[2]">...</select>
```

The jQuery (this uses "select.grupo1" as selector)

```
var sels = $('select.grupo1');
sels.on('change', function() {
    // We want to use the control() function, so
    // we need to build the URL. We may have problems with too many selects,
    // and in that case we will need to modify control().
    control('ocupantes-aptos/dashboard?' + sels.serialize(), 'content');
});
```

The PHP will receive:

```
$selects = $_GET['s'];
foreach ($selects as $num => $val) {
    // Here for example num=1, and val = the selected value of s[1].
}
```

Comment: Man, awesome answer. Can you help me in how can a specify two or more arguments on control?

Comment: yes, but I would need the code for control (). or we can use basic serialize. .. ?

Comment: serialize, please hehe

Comment: added an example. control() uses GET, but with many selects you want POST (and this requires changing the control() function).

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot!